# Woocommerce: Add referrer to info to Order Details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_referral_meta', 10, 1);
function add_referral_meta( $order_id ){
    $ref_url = $_COOKIE['origin']; // Get the cookie
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'referrer', $ref_url ); // Add to order meta
}
```

That is supposed to get the referral URL and add to order meta. However, I cannot see this in the backend for any orders.

How do I add the referrer URL to order notes or order details - so we can see where they came from before making the purchase?

Comment: Can you debug your code and put some hardcoded value to $ref_url to check whether the things are working or not? I'm not sure but can guess something might be wrong with the cookie setup as implementation seems good to go.

Comment: ref_url does contain the referrer URL - however in Woocommerce I cannot see this value anywhere? WooCommerce 6.4.1

Comment: Can you show how you are setting up the cookie?

Comment: The action is in Wordpress functions.php file

Comment: // Set cookie for new users
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie'); // Run when WordPress loads
function set_newuser_cookie() {
    
    $cookie_value = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; // Get URL the user came to your site for
    
    if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['origin'])) { // If not an admin or if cookie doesn't exist already
        setcookie( 'origin', $cookie_value, time()+3600*24*30, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false); // Set cookie for 30 days
    }
}

Comment: It seems, there is something wrong with your custom meta field setting. Are you sure you have created the field correctly where you are storing the value of referrer URL

Comment: Yes, am sure I am - but Woocommerce no longer allow you to view the custom meta fields from the Orders screen? It is no longer listed under Screen Options?

Comment: It is. If you have created it then woocommerce definitely allows you to see that on the order page.

Comment: Check if you have the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin active on your site.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm adding the following code to functions.php does not show the order referrer in Woocommerce orders dashboard:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_referral_meta', 10, 1); function add_referral_meta( $order_id ){ $ref_url = $_COOKIE['origin']; // Get the cookie update_post_meta( $order_id, 'referrer', $ref_url ); // Add to order meta }`